# img src code not render from javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm using ajax json to return some data. Objects that are returned using json have image path which I need to render. Here's the code inside my js function

```
data = '<div class="articleWrapper"><div class="articleImgThumb">' + '<img src="'+item.ImagePath;'" />' + '</div></div>';
```

Something I'm doing wrong cause this code is rendered in my view as

```
<div class="articleWrapper">
  <div class="articleImgThumb"> // here should be img src code </div>
</div>
```

Thanks

Comment: Put your JSON codes here

Comment: Classic typo, and since what follows is actually valid (a string concat you don't store anywhere, effectively a no-op), no error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this:

```
data = '<div class="articleWrapper"><div class="articleImgThumb"><img src="' + item.ImagePath + '" /></div></div>';
```

Answer (score 5):

Try to leave out semi-colon:

```
item.ImagePath
```

instead of:

```
item.ImagePath;
```

and add a  + :

```
item.ImagePath +
```

Comment: Don't just remove the `;`, replace it with a `+` to enable string concatenation

Answer (score 2):

Also, concatenation '+' operator is missed after item.ImagePath

Answer (score 0):

```
data = '<div class="articleWrapper"><div class="articleImgThumb">' + '<img src="' + item.ImagePath + '" />' + '</div></div>';
```

Answer (score 0):

You used **;** instead of **+** after `item.ImagePath`. Try this:

```
data = '<div class="articleWrapper"><div class="articleImgThumb">' + '<img src="'+item.ImagePath+'" />' + '</div></div>';
```